# when i trying to test my Laravel module by phpunit.xml i get error

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm in linux mint and when I just trying to test my project with phpunit in laravel I get this Error :

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)`

and in a few line below this :

`PDOException: could not find driver`

I'm using mysql.

please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Check your `phpunit.xml` file. The `DB_CONNECTION` and/or `DB_DATABASE` environment variables are probably being overruled there.

Comment: in my `.env` file i use two `DB_CONNECTION`. the first connection is **MYSQL** and the second connection is **mongoDB**

Comment: How does your .env, phpunit.xml and database config file look like? If you have a .env.testing file, that one overwrites the .env file.

Comment: I don't have `.env.testing` file . its only `.env` file

@redelschaap

Comment: How does your .env, phpunit.xml and database config file look like?